# How to get number of unread messages from template or plugin in roundcube?

Tags: templates, plugins, skin, roundcube

I have created a new skin and need to show in the header a text saying "You have 3 new mails" for instance. How can I do that from the template, or from the plugin if I need to create one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I have found myself the solution and wanted to share in a case if somebody else will need it. So I have created a plugin and here is the bunch of the code of the plugin needed to extract number of unread message:

```
class test extends rcube_plugin{
    public $task='mail';

    function init(){     
       $this->register_handler('plugin.unreadmessage',array($this, 'unreadmessage_handler'));
    }
    function unreadmessage_handler(){
       $rcmail = rcmail::get_instance();        
       $count=$rcmail->imap->messagecount('INBOX', 'UNSEEN');
       return $count    
    }
}
```

Use it for free!